# AngularJs testing. Where to put template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner, angular-template

I am currently testing an angularjs directive. This directive has a templateUrl. I would lke to test the view to make sure it was initialized correctly i.e. correct number of buttons, certain elements hidden.

The problem I am having is that when I insert my html file into the template cache I still get :

```
"message": "Unexpected request: GET partials/stuff/stuff-leader.html
```

I assumed that when I used the templateCache I would no longer have to use:

```
 $httpBackend.whenGET("partials/stuff/stuff-leader.html").respond([{
        userId: 000
    }]);
```

but this does not seem to be the case. I am wondering am I correctly inserting the template, here is how I am doing it:

```
 template = $templateCache.get('/full/root/disk/path/to/file/stuff/stuff-leader.html');
    $templateCache.put('/myApp/templates/stuff-leader.html',template);
```

Is this correct, or should I be placing it somewhere else?

Comment: Should you not put it with the same relative path as it would be looked for (ie use `partials/stuff` instead of `templates/`)

Comment: Thanks. That works a charm. If you want to put an answer up I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your normal template is looked for at `/partials/stuff/stuff-leader.html`, so this is what you need to inject into the template cache instead of `/myApp/templates/stuff-leader.html`.

Answer (score 1):

You are performing a request with the `$templateCache.get`. Instead do:

```
 beforeEach(inject(function ($templateCache) { $templateCache.put('partials/stuff/stuff-leader.html', '< div >...TemplateCode....< /div >'); }));
```